# ¿Cómo se puede llamar al español hablado en América Latina?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

¿Existe alguna forma especial de llamar al idioma español hablado en América Latina, para diferenciarlo del español hablado en España?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplemente indicar el país. Por ejemplo, *español venezolano*. Cada dialecto, generalmente, no tiene un nombre especialmente definido.

Puedes leer mas información en: [Variedades dialectales del español](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_espa%C3%B1ol#Variedades_dialectales_del_espa.C3.B1ol).

Comunmente en internet se le suele llamar *latino* o *español Latino*.

En otros casos se usa el nombre `Castellano` para identificar el de España exclusivamente, pero existe [mucha polémica al respecto](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_espa%C3%B1ol#Pol.C3.A9mica_en_torno_a_.C2.ABespa.C3.B1ol.C2.BB_o_.C2.ABcastellano.C2.BB) y su uso no es tan generalizado.

Hoy por hoy, lo mejor es especificar directamente.

Comment: En España estudiamos los dialectos de América y las características comunes a todos (o la mayoría) de ellos como "Español de América". Cabe destacar que no existe un "Español de América" como tal porque cada país tiene su variedad, pero es el término paraguas para todos ellos y describe, como ya digo, las características comunes o mayoritarias de estas variedades.

Answer (score 7):

Español latino.

Incluso, por ejemplo, si buscas en youtube series o películas dobladas en cierta página de videos, para diferenciar los tipos de español lo más frecuente es poner "español latino" o simplemente "latino".

Comment: Técnicamente, todo español es latino.  De hecho, "América Latina" se llama eso porque fue habitado hablantes latinos--Español, Portugués, y Francés. Por eso, prefiero yo el término español de Latinomérica, aun que otros entienden "Español Latino" para significar la misma cosa.

Comment: @Flimzy Yo a a veces digo: _Español de Colombia_ pero el término mas común que he escuchado es: _español latino_.